# how to stop my bootstrap fixed static-sidebar not to push content, in mobile view only

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Prevent swipe page when menu toggled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631108/prevent-swipe-page-when-menu-toggled)

the link can show the demo of my sidebar actually offcanvas.I need to stop pushing content in mobile view only.it toggles Body-small class having width of 220px.I applied the width:100%; how to solve it on jquery.

Comment: So you want to.. what exactly on mobile?

Comment: should stop the pushing effect on content div, it should overlay there on content page-wrapper.

Comment: If you want it to overlay instead of push, you need to make the sidemenu `position:relative;` with a negative `left` value to keep it off screen. Then when you open the menu, animate the `left` value so that it slides over

Comment: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/24408045/31874774-9b7d02b0-b7e8-11e7-9192-2067111985a6.PNG         see the screenshot.(In mobile view, sidebar should slide over the content rather pushing it to the side.)that's the issue?